# Where can I post Ansible questions besides Server Fault?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Why can't I post an [Ansible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible_%28software%29)/Windows/Linux question on Stack Overflow?

Stack Overflow would get the best response. I think CM tools involving PowerShell scripting are relevant. I tried to post such a question, and I was told to not post there. Shall I try again? Maybe I don't remember right.

The moderators let me post such questions to Server Fault. Is there a Stack Exchange location where I could get a Stack Overflow-quality response?

Comment: What's different from the responses you've gotten on Server Fault compared to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Generally I get a more thorough on-point, and detailed answer with Stack Overflow.  Why was this question downvoted?  It is -5 one day later.

Answer (score 2):

[**Ansible**](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ansible) **questions are completely on-topic on ServerFault and also SO**. However, cross-posting is frowned upon, so it is advised that you post the question in only one of the two sites.

> Is there a Stack Exchange location where I could get a SO-quality
>   response?

Every SE site has SO level quality, and some do better than that.

> I tried to post such a question, and I was told to not post there

There might be a good reason behind why the mods asked you not to post there, it would be good if you can ask them why, in the chat or as a query on the meta, so that it would further help you in site selection for asking questions in the future.

Comment: *Every SE site has SO level quality, and some do better than that.* ... only in a perfect world... A lot of the more subjective sites have very low answer quality.